# Grep and cat cause Terminal to hangup. Terminal displays process going but nothing happens

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, cat

Learning command line as basis for further web development learning.
Using a Mac whenever I try to use GREP or CAT, Terminal hangs up. Once I enter the process it displays in the top border, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you passing an argument to these commands? You should do `cat <file>` or `cat <file> | grep <something>`.

Comment: Are you missing a closing quote ?

Comment: Please give an example of the offending 'grep' or 'cat', or provide a shell script that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you just type

```
$ cat
```

at the command line, the shell will wait for further input, because you haven't given it any input to work on.

`cat` will take its input and send it to wherever you're sending its output. By default, this is to stdout: the terminal. So you can start with something like this:

```
/Users/jpk/:510 $ cat 
dog boy van
dog boy van
foo bar baz
foo bar baz
^D
/Users/jpk/:511 $
```

When I type `cat` and hit return, the shell waits until some input comes in, and then it redirects that to the output. This goes on until I send an end-of-file signal (^D)

I'm not sure what you're seeing for  `grep` - when I just type a bare `grep` and hit enter,  I get usage notes:

```
/Users/jpk/:512 $ grep
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

/Users/jpk/:513 $
```

Comment: That's not quite correct. `grep` by itself is certainly a complete command. The reason the shell waits is because if a filename is not given, input is expected to come from STDIN.

Comment: That's correct - I was actually editing that just now. :) Thanks for the correction.